# how to do an if statement in javascript to check if a JSON array is empty?

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays, json, if-statement

I am trying various answers from stack overflow to write an if statement which check is JSON array is populated or empty. However, console.log is always returning undefined. I am using node.js and webstorm as IDE. can I get some help to solve this?

```
function selectData(){
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM cust where LastName = '" +registerArray[0]+"'";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); //correctly displaying stuffs from db
        if (result) { //statement not working correctly.
            var pw = "SELECT ID FROM cust where LastName = '" +registerArray[0]+"'";
            con.query(pw, function (err, result) {
                var idcheck  = JSON.stringify(result);
                console.log(result); //always shows undefined
                if (idcheck !== registerArray[0]){
                    return ("{re enter correct password}");
                } else {
                    return ("{login successfully}");
                }
            });

        } else {
            return("{sign up first}");
        }
    });
}
con.end();
```

}

Comment: Simply do `if (result)` it will check if `result` is a falsy or truthy value

Comment: your query is vulnerable to "sql injection" attack. `con.query("SELECT * FROM cust WHERE LastName = ?", [registerArray[0]], function (err, res) { ... })` is what you want to use

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` give you?

Comment: @iArcadia the second console.log(JSON.stringify(result)) gives undefined

Comment: @KunalMukherjee how should I use it?

Comment: @teddy As @Kunal Mukherjee said, `if (result)` instead of `if (result.length !== 0)` should work.

Comment: changed my code. but it is still displaying undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using strict equality operator with con.query which returns a null array `([])` if it didn't found anything. 
Since you're using strict comparison `([]) !== 0` resolves to TRUE which causes your problem.

**Solution**

You could change your statement to `if (result)` or, a clearer more verbose version, `if (result.length > 0 )` which would acomplish what you're trying to do.

You can learn more about how JS evaluates expressions from this article 
[Truthy and falsy values in javascript](http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-javascript.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use Object.keys

```
function selectData(){
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM cust where LastName = '" +registerArray[0]+"'";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        if (Object.keys(result).length !== 0 ){
```

Comment: still showing undefined. Giving this error on my client side:  VM19:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.SendLoginData.xhttp.onreadystatechange

Comment: The code you have posted does not contain JSON.parse

Answer (score -1):

To check undefined and that there's items...

```
if (result !== undefined && Object.keys(result).length !== 0) {
     //you've got an object and it has some stuff 
} else {
     //handle situation where you've got nothing
}
```

Edit: apparently, you're not supposed to use getOwnPropertyNames as some secure frameworks will block it.. use Object.keys instead.